# Type of UK visa to attend convocation

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, application-status

Can anyone tell me what kind of visa it will be if i apply to attend mrcp convocation ceremony in edinburgh. The types of visa are confusing.

Comment: What types did you consider? Why are you having trouble deciding which of those is correct?

Comment: OP comments reveal 'post-submission-anxiety' so tagging accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Attending a convocation in Edinburgh is a personal objective and you would apply for a [Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/overview).  To do this, you would open an account at [Visa4UK](https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/home/welcome) and create a new application.

The first set of questions on the application would be filled out like this screen shot...

[image]

For the generic case, that's really all there is to it.

You have a [previous refusal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60711/got-refused-for-uk-visa) where they got you on funds parking. Hopefully you are in a position to make a better presentation to the decision-maker.  There are some reasonably priced advisers at [The Association of Regulated Immigration Advisers](https://ariauk.wordpress.com/contact-aria/) and for heavy lifting (which I recommend in your case) your can check out the [Immigration Law Practitioners Association](http://www.ilpa.org.uk/search-directory.php).  And the main point of reference for finding a solicitor is the [UK Law Society](http://solicitors.lawsociety.org.uk/).

I would also recommend that you make a careful read of [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) before assembling your evidence. There's more background reading at [proof-provenance-of-funds](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-provenance-of-funds).

Note: disclosing that I am a long-term, contributing member in good standing at those resources I linked to.

Comment: @HankyPanky check this link http://travel.stackexchange.com/users/37847/farah